# Change where navigation bar links?

Tags: menus, navigation

I have a client with a WordPress blog who wants to have her website run two separate websites in the same WordPress installation by duplicating pages and changing the place that the navigation bar links. I can easily duplicate the page, but when I do it just adds a copy of the same link.

Is there any way I can hide page links on certain pages?